# Storing large text constants using SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best practice for storing a very long text string of random characters when using an SQL Statement? I am doing something like this:

```
insert into tblMyTable (MyID,MyText) values (1,'this is a very long text which could contain punctuation and odd characters');
```

I know you should double the single quotes found in the string so they do not get interpreted as the delimiters, but are their other considerings in conditioning the string constant?

MyText is a `varchar(max)`

Comment: Use parameterized queries

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean by "storing"? What problems do you expect, and what solutions are you considering / have you researched?

Comment: I suppose that is my question, is there anything else I can expect from the experiences of the users out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use parameterized sql (which I highly recommend) you don't need to worry about double quotes.

```
declare @MyID int = 1;
declare @MyText varchar(max) = 'this is a very long text which could contain punctuation and odd characters';

insert into tblMyTable (MyID,MyText) values (@MyID, @MyText);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sean mentioned, parameterized sql is a clean solution. But you do still need to worry about two single quotes.

```
   declare @MyID int = 1;

-- single quote bad
--    declare @MyText varchar(max) = 'this is a very long text which could've contained punctuation and odd characters';

-- two single quotes good
      declare @MyText varchar(max) = 'this is a very long text which could''ve contained punctuation and odd characters';

select @MyID, @MyText
```

Comment: This is true but most of the time you don't set the value in sql, they are set in the application. From the application you would not want to double your quotes our your actual data will have double quotes.

Comment: You are right, if you're calling the proc from app. But if you're just SSMS-ing, you need the double single quotes. :)